# AttributeError: module 'distutils' has no attribute 'version'

Tags: pytorch, attributeerror, tensorboard

I can't get analytics output from tensorboard

pytorch version == 1.9.0,
tensorboard version == 2.6.0

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "optim.py", line 7, in <module>
    from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/score-denoise/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/tensorboard/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    LooseVersion = distutils.version.LooseVersion
AttributeError: module 'distutils' has no attribute 'version'
```

I found a project that uses exactly these versions of libraries, installed them, but it didn't start working, how to solve this problem?

I found this link with a similar problem, but I didn't find a solution to it. https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/69894

Comment: It's [this comment](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/69894#issuecomment-1080635462) you're looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What exactly did you do? Did you do this?

`pip install setuptools==59.5.0`

If yes, did the error change?